# Line Split Issues when Copying Data from SQL Server to files in Azure data factory:

Tags: azure, data-ingestion

When I pull the data from Onpremise SQL Server to ADL, rows are getting split into multiple lines whenever any column is having Multi-line texts(Carriage return or Line feeds) in ADF.

I have used "|" as column delimiter and also used " as Quote character. Due to this issue my data set is completely messed up

The quoted text should come in one column instead of spliting into multiple lines